VSCode will not recognize python module, even though it is installed in the correct environment
I have a module called "pycrossword" and in the program, VSCode cannot read or recognize the module. There is only one interpreter on my machine and VSCode is aimed right at it. The module IS installed in the correct location. I have uninstalled everything related, but it is a no-go. Even PYCharm will not see it. The module shows up on the pip list. Help? Please?
I went to ChatGPT and followed its hints to uninstall everything, to no avail. I have messed around with JSON (adding path to python and the module) no avail. So, I am at a complete loss.
This is my terminal output:
PS D:\PTest> & C:/Users/jb_in/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe d:/PTest/Ttest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\PTest\Ttest.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pycrossword
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycrossword'

The pip list:
PS D:\PTest> pip list
Package                   Version
------------------------- -----------
altair                    5.3.0
altgraph                  0.17.4
attrs                     23.2.0
certifi                   2024.6.2
charset-normalizer        3.3.2
idna                      3.7
jedi                      0.19.1
Jinja2                    3.1.4
jsonschema                4.22.0
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1
MarkupSafe                2.1.5
numpy                     1.26.4
packaging                 24.0
pandas                    2.2.2
parso                     0.8.4
pefile                    2023.2.7
pip                       24.0
pycrossword               0.4.0.3
pygame                    2.5.2
pyinstaller               6.7.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2024.6
PyQt5                     5.15.10
PyQt5-Qt5                 5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                 12.13.0
python-dateutil           2.9.0.post0
pytz                      2024.1
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.2
pyword                    1.0
QScintilla                2.14.1
referencing               0.35.1
requests                  2.32.3
rpds-py                   0.18.1
setuptools                70.0.0
six                       1.16.0
toolz                     0.12.1
tzdata                    2024.1
urllib3                   2.2.1
Yapsy                     1.12.2

PS D:\PTest> pip show pycrossword
Name: pycrossword
Version: 0.4.0.3
Summary: pycrossword - the Python Crossword Puzzle Generator and Editor
Home-page: https://github.com/S0mbre/crossword.git
Author: Iskander Shafikov (S0mbre)
Author-email: s00mbre@gmail.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: C:\Users\jb_in\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
Requires: altair, jedi, numpy, pandas, pip, PyQt5, QScintilla, requests, yapsy
Required-by:


Is pycrossword even the right import? Looks like it might be import pycross

Oh, how did you get to that? (I am new to python).

I looked up the github repo and noticed the package name was pycross (there is a "pycross" directory at the root https://github.com/S0mbre/crossword)

Thank you. OK. Well that solved that problem. Now it is pyword causing a ruckus. It is like whack-a-mole.
